# ngrok respond 503 code

Tags: linux, ngrok

On server side I run

```
./bin/ngrokd -domain="$NGROK_DOMAIN" -httpAddr=":8088" -httpsAddr=":8082" -tunnelAddr=":8083"
```

Display

```
[18:39:55 CST 2017/07/18] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [registry] [tun] No affinity cache specified
[18:39:55 CST 2017/07/18] [INFO] (ngrok/log.(*PrefixLogger).Info:83) [metrics] Reporting every 30 seconds
[18:39:55 CST 2017/07/18] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Listening for public http connections on [::]:8088
[18:39:55 CST 2017/07/18] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Listening for public https connections on[::]:8082
[18:39:55 CST 2017/07/18] [INFO] (ngrok/log.Info:112) Listening for control and proxy connections on [::]:8083
```

On client side I run

```
./ngrok -subdomain=ym -config="ngrok-config" start tunnel1
```

Display

```
ngrok                                                                           (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       1.7/1.7
Forwarding                    http://ym.t.kmic168.com:8088 -> 127.0.0.1:81
Web Interface                 127.0.0.1:4040
# Conn                        0
Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms
```

I already set nginx config.

But try http://ym.t.kmic168.com:8088/ on browser

```
respond 503 code
```

please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a A record just like "*.t" to your ip